Changing measure in a Lebesgue integral
I'm self studying Capinski and Kopp's Measure, Integral, and Probability.
I'm struggling to understand the proof of Theorem 4.41:

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and a random variable $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $$ \int_{\Omega} g\left( X \left( \omega \right) \right) \, \text{d}P\left(\omega\right) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) \, \text{d} P_{X} (x)$$

The function $g$ is not described in the theorem, presumably it is measurable and integrable.
The book defines the probability distribution of $X$ as $P_{X} (B) = P (X^{-1} (B))$ on the $\sigma$-field of Borel sets $B$. I'm only interested in the case where the function $g$ is an indicator function.
The book provides the following proof for this case:

For an indicator function $g = 1_{A}$ we have $P(X \in A)$ on both sides.

I'm having trouble showing this, as I'm not quite sure I understand the notation.
For example:
Using the standard Lebesgue measure $m$ and the book's notation, the integral of the function $g = 1_{A}$ over the measurable set $E$ is
$$ \int_{E} 1_{A} \, \text{d} m  = m(A \cap E).$$
Does it follow that $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{A} (x) \, \text{d}P_{X} (x) = P_{X} (A \cap \mathbb{R}) = P_{X} (A)?$$
I would very much appreciate a fleshed out proof, making the minor details explicit.

If $(X,\mathscr A,\mu)$ is a measure space, and $A\in\mathscr A$, then $\int_X\chi_A,\mathrm{d}\mu=\mu(A)$.

Note that $P(X\in A)$ is just a symbol for $P(\{\omega\in \Omega : X(\omega)\in A\})$.
$$\int_{\Omega} 1_A(X(\omega))dP(\omega)  = \int_{X\in A} 1 dP + \int_{X\not\in A} 0 dp = P(X\in A)$$
$$\int_{\Omega} 1_A dP_X = P_X(A) = P(X^{-1}(A)) = P(\{\omega\in \Omega : X(\omega)\in A\}) = P(X\in A)$$
